# SWITCH - How to show quantity of switched ON rows?

Tags: field-pack

I need to show how much rows in the entry have "ON" state. 
I could not find any tag in documentary.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looping channel entries you could add a second loop to grab the "On" entries...

```
{!-- first loop to display entries --}
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel"}
  {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{!-- second loop to grab 'on' entries --}
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel" search:your_switch_field="ON"}
  {if count == total_results}
    {total_results}
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```